# Accordion Inside Accordion twitter bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I'm trying to implement an accordion inside another accordion using Twitter Bootstrap. Is it possible? if so, then please help me with the code because i tried implementing it but I wasn't successful.

Comment: could you please post the code you are using and what exactly went wrong

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply include another accordion inside the div with the class accordion-inner:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordion1">
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group #1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
      <div class="accordion-inner">
        This is a simple accordion inner content...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-group">
    <div class="accordion-heading">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group #2 (With nested accordion inside)
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
      <div class="accordion-inner">

        <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->

        <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne">
                Collapsible Inner Group Item #1
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="accordion-group">
            <div class="accordion-heading">
              <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerTwo">
                Collapsible Inner Group Item #2
              </a>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
              <div class="accordion-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>          

        <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Remember to use different accordion ids.

Comment: also, the id of collapse on:
<div id="collapse **Two** "...
Needs to change with the accordion id.

Answer (score 16):

this is working more fluidly in Bootstrap v3.2.0

```
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group #1
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                This is a simple accordion inner content...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
                Collapsible Group #2 (With nested accordion inside)
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">

                <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->

                <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne">
                        Collapsible Inner Group Item #1
                      </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerTwo">
                        Collapsible Inner Group Item #2
                      </a></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        Anim pariatur cliche...
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Great answer inner accordion moves much smoother than the previous answer which jumps a little during animation,

Answer (score 10):

I found that solution from Alessandro is not working with Bootstrap 3. Here is a working one (slightly different, with no default expanded panel. If you need any, just add "in" class):

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne">
      Collapsible Group #1
      </a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-body collapse">
      <div class="panel-inner">
        This is a simple accordion inner content...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
        Collapsible Group #2 (With nested accordion inside)
      </a></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-body collapse">
      <div class="panel-inner">

        <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerOne">
                Collapsible Inner Group Item #1
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="panel-body collapse">
              <div class="panel-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title"><a class="panel-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseInnerTwo">
                Collapsible Inner Group Item #2
              </a></h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="panel-body collapse">
              <div class="panel-inner">
                Anim pariatur cliche...
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use collapse events on nested collapsible elements it helps stopping collapse events from bubbling up above panel-group level. Otherwise collapse events fired by inner collapsible elements will reach to outer elements trying to handle collapse events fired by their own collapsible elements, and cause unexpected behavior.

```
$('.panel-group').on('show.bs.collapse shown.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This example presumes that you use "panel-group" as class name to group collapsible elements.