# php array to bootstrap accordion

Tags: php, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

This is a simple bootstrap accordion:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#_1-1">XXX</div>
        <div id="_1-1" class="panel-collapse collapse">XXX</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#_1-2">XXX</div>
        <div id="_1-2" class="panel-collapse collapse">#accordion2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#_1-3">XXX</div>
        <div id="_1-3" class="panel-collapse collapse">XXX</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To create a sub accordion, we can copy `#accordion1` and paste on the `accordion2` text

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/9rxw1poj/) there is an example of what I want to obtain, by "convert" a PHP array into accordion, e.g:

```
<?php
$unit = array (
    "unit1" => array(
        "outcome1-1" => "element1-1",
        "outcome1-2" => "element1-2"
    ),
    "unit2" => array(
        "outcome2-1" => array(
            "picture2-1" => "img2-1"
        ),
        "outcome2-2" => "element2-2"
    ),
    "unit3" => array(
        "outcome3-1" => "element3-1",
        "outcome3-2" => "element3-2"
    )
);
?>
```

Here is how I am trying to dynamically generate the bootstrap accordion:

```
<?php
function array2accordion($array, $level = 1) {

    $out='<div id="accordion'.$level.'" class="panel-group">';

    $i=0; foreach($array as $key => $elem){ $i++;

        if(!is_array($elem)){

            $out=$out.'
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'.$level.'" data-target="#_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'">'.$key.'</div>
                <div id="_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'.$key.'</div>
            </div>';

        }else{
            $out=$out.'
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'.$level.'" data-target="#_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'">'.$key.'</div>
                <div id="_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'.array2accordion($elem, $level + 1).'</div>
            </div>';
        }
    }

    $out=$out.'</div>';

    return $out; 
}

echo array2accordion($unit);
?>
```

Actually it is not working properly, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JFDion [There](http://codepad.viper-7.com/zf9JNm)is what I am trying just now, but it is not working at all... Actually I am a bit confused because I have not idea how to dynamically recreate the accordion structure... It is driving me crazy from all the day

Comment: I think the thing that you were missing over here is the concatenation operator after first `$out .=`

Comment: @Uchiha please can you explain it more specifically

Answer (score 2):

I thing that this is going to help you:

```
<?php
function generateAccordion(array $values){
    $i = 1;
$html_accordion = '<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">';
foreach( $values as $id => $items){
    $html_accordion .= <<<HTML
        <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion3" data-target="#$id">Collapse Nro. $i</div>
        <div id="$id" class="panel-collapse collapse">
HTML;
    foreach($items as $item){
        $html_accordion .= <<<HTML
            <p><a href="#" >$item</a></p>
HTML;
    }//end foreach items

    $html_accordion .= '</div></div>';
    $i++;
}//end foreach collapses elements
$html_accordion .= '</div>';
    return $html_accordion;

}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <?php
############################################################################
            //Put here your values:                                
            $accordion1 = array(
                    //$id => [val1, val2, ...]
                    "_1-1" => ["a1", "a2", "a3"],
                    "_1-2" => ["b1", "b2", "b3"],
                    "_1-3" => ["c1", "c2", "c3","c4"]
                    //and so on...
            );
            //output:
            echo generateAccordion($accordion1);
#############################################################################            
        ?>
    </div>

      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->    
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

You should put in $accordion1 array the items that you want show in the accordion.

**Edit**

In your updated code you are forgetting the accordion-inner class::

```
 "<div class="accordion-inner">...</div>"
```

See this post [Accordion Inside Accordion twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558941/accordion-inside-accordion-twitter-bootstrap)

Here is your code updated:

```
function array2accordion($array, $level = 1) {

    $out='<div id="accordion'.$level.'" class="panel-group">';
    $out.='<div class="accordion-inner">';//LOOK ME!!!

    $i=0; 

    foreach($array as $key => $elem){ $i++;
        if(!is_array($elem)){

            $out=$out.'
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'.$level.'" data-target="#_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'">'.$key.'</div>
                <div id="_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'.$key.'</div>
            </div>';

        }else{
            $out=$out.'
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion'.$level.'" data-target="#_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'">'.$key.'</div>
                <div id="_'.$key.$level.'-'.$key.$i.'" class="panel-collapse collapse">'.array2accordion($elem, $level + 1).'</div>
            </div>';
        }
    }

    $out=$out.'</div>';
    $out=$out.'</div>';

    return $out; 
}

echo array2accordion($unit);
?>
```

If this don't help you, let me know ;)

Comment: Can you have a look to the updated the code in my question please

Comment: Did you try by putting the "accordion-ineer" class? (See the Edit section above).