# Creating a dynamic form with dynamic fields

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I'm trying to create a form which has an infinite numbers of collapsible groups and inner groups.

I'm stuck in how to do it, because each input/collapsible needs to have a unique id.

Actually, I have this piece of code: (extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558941/accordion-inside-accordion-twitter-bootstrap))

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">

        <div class="panel panel-warning">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo">
                        Collapsible Group #2 (With nested accordion inside)
                    </a></h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">

                    <!-- Here we insert another nested accordion -->

                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2">

                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
                                                           href="#collapseInnerOne">
                                        Collapsible Inner Group Item #1
                                    </a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseInnerOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    First name:<br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
                                    Last name:<br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel panel-primary">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2"
                                                           href="#collapseInnerTwo">
                                        Collapsible Inner Group Item #2
                                    </a></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div id="collapseInnerTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    First name:<br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstname"><br>
                                    Last name:<br>
                                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastname">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <!-- Inner accordion ends here -->

                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary"> Add dynamic inner group</button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-warning"> Add collapsible group</button>
    </div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Basically, when the user clicks in the orange button "Add collapsible group" the code needs to create a new Collapsible Group with an ID (to get from input form later) and when the user clicks in the blue button "Add dynamic inner group" the code needs to create a new "Collapsible Inner Group Item" with ther own inputs and ids.

I tried a lot of things, my actually code [here](http://pastebin.com/eFQ8cHyA) (There is a lot of unrelated code here) don't work and I don't know what to do, I don't have experience with Jquery.

Any help or hints will be appreciated, thanks.